# Unable to create file - EACCESS Permission Denied

Tags: android, file-io, android-permissions

I'm writing some text into a file, yet before even writing the text, I am unable to create the file itself.

```
File newxmlfile = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "new.xml");
                XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
                try {
                    newxmlfile.createNewFile();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("IOException", "exception in createNewFile() method",
                            e);
                }
```

Permission is set fine.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

SDCard is writable and mounted also.

However, I kept getting

```
07-11 11:23:01.134: E/IOException(5363): exception in createNewFile() method
07-11 11:23:01.134: E/IOException(5363): java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
07-11 11:23:01.134: E/IOException(5363):    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948)
07-11 11:23:01.134: E/IOException(5363):    at com.app.example.MainActivity$LongOperation.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:71)
07-11 11:23:01.134: E/IOException(5363):    at com.app.example.MainActivity$LongOperation.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-11 11:23:01.134: E/IOException(5363):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-11 11:23:01.134: E/IOException(5363):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-11 11:23:01.134: E/IOException(5363):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-11 11:23:01.134: E/IOException(5363):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-11 11:23:01.134: E/IOException(5363):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-11 11:23:01.134: E/IOException(5363):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-11 11:23:01.134: E/IOException(5363): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
07-11 11:23:01.134: E/IOException(5363):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
07-11 11:23:01.134: E/IOException(5363):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
07-11 11:23:01.134: E/IOException(5363):    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:941)
07-11 11:23:01.134: E/IOException(5363):    ... 8 more
07-11 11:23:01.134: E/FileNotFoundException(5363): can't create FileOutputStream
```

Comment: Instead of this `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "\new.xml")` try this  `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +File.Seperator+ "new.xml")`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, you just need to add an extra `/` (or `File.separator`) before the file name as follows:

```
File newxmlfile = new File(
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/new.xml");
XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
try {
    newxmlfile.createNewFile();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("IOException", "exception in createNewFile() method",
            e);
}
```